# Can I save a users gmail contacts in the database for later use?

Tags: google-api, privacy

Once a user has authed my application to fetch his contacts, would it be allowed to save all the contacts in a database for later use?

I wonder if there would be any restrictions to this.

This way we could prevent the user from authoring every time we need to use his contacts.

Answer (score 1):

You already got the contacts, I don't see why you wouldn't be allowed to save it. Obviously it's always nice to make it clear to the user what you're doing and maybe give an opt-out option.